# How can I catch all index out of range errors in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am calculating the distance between pixels, I just made a mouse callback function in the program for calculating x and y coordinates.

Here is the code, what I tried,

```py
def distance():
    length = len(position)
    # Distance in terms of x
    distance_value = position[length-1][0] - position[length-2][0]
    # Distance in terms of y
    # distance_value = position[length-1][1] - position[length-2][1]

    print("Value of pixel is: " + str(distance_value))
```

> IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: `try: #some part except IndexError: pass` wohoo!

Comment: what is Position ?

Comment: while clicking the mouse, getting the coordinates of x and y and then stored in a list. from where we have to take position of the value

Comment: The best idea would be not to cause them in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do the following:

```
def distance():
    length = len(position)
    # Distance in terms of x
    try:
        distance_value = position[length-1][0] - position[length-2][0]
        print("Value of pixel is: " + str(distance_value))
    except IndexError as e:
        print('There is an error')
        print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `position` is a list of x, y pairs. So at the first position, your program fails since there is no position to compare.
In this case, you can also use an `if` statement rather than the `try` statement, which would catch all `IndexError` i.e. you prevent the error from occurring rather than catching it.

```
if len(position) > 1:
    distance_value = position[-1][0] - position[-2][0]
```

Note, you should rather use negative indices in order to refer to the last elements than
`length - x`